# cant receive data in all clients angular / nest js scoket io

Tags: angular, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

i'm trying to use socket io in a small project so im using **angular** and **nestjs**
but im receiving the data only at the same client that im sending the data from

the other clients dont reload their components after every message i think the problem is from the client side but i cant figure it out

***nestjs***

```
implements OnGatewayDisconnect, OnGatewayConnection {
  private logger: Logger = new Logger('AppGateway');
  constructor() {}
  handleConnection(client: Socket) {
    this.logger.log(`client Connected ${client.id}`);
  }
  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    this.logger.log(`client disconnected ${client.id}`);
  }
  @SubscribeMessage('chat')
  handleMessage(client: Socket, data: any) {
    client.emit('chat', data);
  }
  @SubscribeMessage('typing')
  handleMessage2(client: Socket, data: any) {
    client.emit('typing', data);
  }
}
```

***angular service***

```
export class MessageService {
  socket: any;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
  }

  listen(eventname: string): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((subscriber) => {
      this.socket.on(eventname, (data) => {
        subscriber.next(data);
      });
    });
  }

  emit(eventname: string, data: any) {
    this.socket.emit(eventname, data);
  }
}
```

***angular component.ts***

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this.messageService
      .listen('typing')
      .subscribe((data) => this.updateFeedback(data));
    this.messageService
      .listen('chat')
      .subscribe((data) => this.updateMessage(data));
   
  }
 updateMessage(data: any) {
    this.feedback = '';
    if (!!!data) return;
    console.log(`${data.handle} : ${data.message}`);
    this.output.push(data);
  }

  updateFeedback(data: any) {
    this.feedback = `${data} is typing a message`;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**update**: the problem is when you emit the data to the client you need i used client.emit and client is a socket.
so i tried using this code and it worked fine

```
@WebSocketServer() server: Server;
  @SubscribeMessage('chat')
  handleMessage(client: Socket, data: any) {
    this.msg = data;
    this.server.emit('chat', data);
    return 'hello';
  }
```